# Is it Possible to undo a typed character into a JText area?

Tags: java, swing, events

Is it possible to remove the character typed into a JTextArea in Java Swing? Or block certain characters from being added? I am not talking about a replace, I specifically want to remove / block the character added by a key event. Here's some example code to illustrate what I want to do:

```
      input.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){
            //Nothing to do here
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(condition == true){
            e.undo();
            //I want to remove the key that character that was inserted with this action
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            //Nothing to do here
        }

    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Ood you must find which characters you don't want to enter in that text area, get a Key code of that character if the entered character is equal to key code call keyevent.consume();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the content of the textfield at the end of the keyPressed method.
If you then encounter a key, that you don't want, you can set the content of the textfield to the stored value and return.

```
private String oldValue;

@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        if(condition == true){
            setText(oldValue);
            return;
        }
        oldvalue = getText();//Replace getText() with correct getter for current value
    }
```

Comment: This is a very good idea! Thank you!

Comment: `This is a very good idea!` - not really. A KeyListener was used with AWT. However, when using Swing you have access to newer and better API's. Instead you should be using a `DocumentFilter`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for more information and examples.